# Вывод нескольких статусов элемента при формировании массива

Tags: php, битрикс

Выбираются элементов с фильтрацией:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL", "EDIT_LINK", "DELETE_LINK");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y", '=PROPERTY_STATYS' => Array(2,1));
```

В этоv `div` выводится элементы с фильтром:

```
<div class="panel-body second-links">
<?foreach ($arElement as $arElementItem):                                                       
   if ($arSection['ID'] == $arElementItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']):?>
<p>
<a class="open_lot" 
    href="javascript:void(0);" 
    url="<?=$arElementItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>" 
    idElement="<?=$arElementItem['ID']?>">
                                         <?=$arElementItem['NAME']?>
</a>
</p>    
<?endif;
endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Как задать условие чтобы элементам со значением фильтра `$arFilter["=PROPERTY_STATYS"] == '2'` выводился с таким статусом

```
<a style="color: green">Принимаются заявки</a>
```

или

```
$arFilter["=PROPERTY_STATYS"] == '1'
 <a style="color: green">На рассмотрении</a>
```

Comment: так сделайте `print_r($arElementItem)` и смотрите, где там STATYS значение... но по сути будет что-то типа `if($arElementItem["PROPERTIES"]["STATYS"]["VALUE"] == "2"){ echo "ваша ссылка";}elseif($arElementItem["PROPERTIES"]["STATYS"]["VALUE"] == "1"){ echo "другая ссылка";}`.

Comment: @Oleksandr Так в том то и беда что в массиве **$arElementItem** нет свойства STATYS. Только в массиве **$arFilter** есть "=PROPERTY_STATYS" по которому все фильтруется, вот и думаю как к нему обратиться

Comment: массив $arSelect у вас ведь и не имеет этого свойства... Добавте его туда

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать:

```
$arElementItem['PROPERTY_STATYS_VALUE'] == '1'
```

вместо `$arFilter["=PROPERTY_STATYS"] == '1'`

Comment: Какие-то объяснения не желаете добавить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте хотя бы краткое пояснение.

Comment: Добрый день!
Комментарий добавил изначально тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520523/the-condition-of-the-output-of-elements-does-not-work/46562508#46562508
Дело в том, что массив $arFilter собирается в файле component.php и задается принцип фильтрации элементов. Когда же мы выводим данные на страницу (это в файле template.php) мы получаем данные в массиве $arResult 
Из примера видно - автор кастомизирует битриксовый компонент, где $arResult через foreach выводится как $arElementItem 
И уже именно $arElementItem содержит все свойства
Вопросы - isingwithaz@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю вы элементы достаете при помощи АПИ?

Добавьте в arSelect  PROPERTY_STATYS  и далее анализируйте $arElementItem['PROPERTY_STATYS_VALUE']

Comment: Нет там такого значения **PROPERTY_STATYS** тогда я бы конечно обратился бы. почему нельзя обратиться к $arFilter и по нему определять. Если 1 то такой статус , если 2 то такой...

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov как его не может быть, если вы по нему фильтруете? О_О

Comment: @Oleksandr я не знаю вот что, в моем массиве
`$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL", "EDIT_LINK", "DELETE_LINK", "PROPERY_STATYS");`
и то что выводит var_dump
`array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "ID" [1]=> string(9) "IBLOCK_ID" [2]=> string(4) "NAME" [3]=> string(17) "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" [4]=> string(15) "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" [5]=> string(9) "EDIT_LINK" [6]=> string(11) "DELETE_LINK" [7]=> string(14) "PROPERY_STATYS" }`

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov PROPERY_STATYS != PROPERTY_STATYS

Comment: @Oleksandr даже без опечатки все равно пустое PROPERTY_STATYS = NULL и все хоть что делай, не понимаю почему не выводиться никак

Comment: Ну есть же документация https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php

Если у вас в инфоблоке есть свойство STATYS (это символьный код свойства) то вы можете его и выбирать и фильтровать по нему. При этом в методе CIblockElement::GetList в выбираемых полях вам необходимо указывать PROPERTY_STATYS (кроме того в выбираемые поля над добавить и IBLOCK_ID). В результате у вас должно появиться целый набор полей PROPERTY_STATYS_*  .  Если таковых не появляется значит ищите ошибку или опечатку. (не тот инфоблок, не тот символьный код свойства)....